# Finding limit of this function

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Given function: f(x) = $\sqrt{x^2+x}-x$

I used 3th binomial formula and brought it to this form:

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}$

But now no idea how to get limit of this (goes to ∞). By testing I know it is 0.5

Comment: Do you know Taylor series expansion ?

Comment: No and we may not use things we dont know :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}=\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+x}.$$

If you want the limit at $+\infty $, then you can take $x>0$, and if you want at $-\infty $, then you can take $x<0$ and conclude.

**Added**

If you want the limit to $+\infty $, then you suppose $x>0$, and thus $|x|=x$. Therefore,
$$\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+1}$$
and thus, the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I would be on the right path if I factored out x in both numerator and denominator? I think it will look even more complicated ^^

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it's fine now.

Comment: Hehe thanks a lot Surb!, sorry I couldnt see myself :')

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use a substitution, in this case $t=1/x$, that transforms the limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-1}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1+t/2+o(t)-1}{t}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
After the first equality sign you can immediately recognize a derivative. If you can't use Taylor expansions, you can do
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-1}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{(\sqrt{1+t}-1)(\sqrt{1+t}+1)}{t(\sqrt{1+t}+1)}
=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}+1}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

---

Note that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+x}-x)=\infty$ without any need to do transformations, because both summands have limit $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply with conjugate,

$$\frac{(\sqrt {x^2+x} - x) (\sqrt {x^2+x} + x)} {\sqrt{x^2+x} + x}$$

$$\frac{x} {\sqrt{x^2+x} + x}$$

$$\frac{x} {\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{1}{x})} + x}$$

$$\frac{x} {x\sqrt {(1+\frac{1}{x} )}+ x}$$

$$\frac{1} {\sqrt {(1+\frac{1}{x} )}+ 1}$$

Now take limit